# How many Imperial Inquisitors are there?

Tags: star-wars

In the Disney canon, the inquisitors more or less replace the role of the Emperors hands from legends. But I do not recall seeing an exact number or figure that tells us just how many Inquisitors there are.

The ones I do know about: 
Grand Inquisitor, Fallen order and Rebels Inquisitors, along with some in the Vader comics- Example: Vader kills an entire sect of Inquisitors for suspected treason, there were about ten Just in the comic!

So, is there an official canon cap to the amount of inquisitors, or if a Jedi falls to the dark side do they just become another Inquisitor?

Comment: There are as many Imperial Inquisitors as there are plot holes.

Comment: To that matter, out of curiosity, I know of two Emperors hands, were there any others?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Currently, there is no definitive answer to how many inquisitors there are.

The number seems to shift every year. These are the ones we do know (spoilers for all inquisitor appearances):

- **The Grand Inquisitor** (possibly the First Brother?) - Former Jedi Temple guard, leader of the Inquisitorius, defeated by Kanan Jarrus in combat, killed himself (*Star Wars Rebels*).
- **Second Sister** - Former Padawan of Cere Junda. Hunted Cal Kestis and co. After leaving the Dark Side, executed by Darth Vader (*Jedi: Fallen Order*).
- **Fourth Sister** - Identity assumed by rebel commander Lina Graf in order to rescue an Alliance member from Fortress Vader on Mustafar. Ambiguous on the reality of this one, but real enough to be included (*Star Wars Adventures: Return to Vader's Castle*).
- **Fifth Brother** - After the death of the Grand Inquisitor, one of the primary hunters of the Lothal rebels. Killed by Maul on Malachor (*Star Wars Rebels*).
- **Sixth Brother** - Part of the Inquisitorious forces during the Occupation of Mon Cala. Disables Ninth Sister to escape malfunctioning purge troopers. Tracks Ahsoka Tano down to the planet Raada and killed by his own exploding lightsaber (*Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith*, *Ahsoka*).
- **Seventh Sister** - After the death of the Grand Inquisitor, one of the primary hunters of the Lothal rebels. Killed by Maul on Malachor (*Star Wars Rebels*).
- **Eighth Brother** - Seems to be primarily focused on hunting Maul on Malachor. After his lightsaber is damaged, he falls to his death after attempting to fly away like an idiot (*Star Wars Rebels*).
- **Ninth Sister** - Admits to having been a Jedi, before joining the Dark Side because it's cool, essentially. Loses several limbs over the course of her career, force pushed by Cal Kestis on Kashyyyk, possibly alive (*Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith*, *Jedi: Fallen Order*)?
- **Tenth Brother** - Former Jedi Prosset Dibs, disillusioned with the Jedi after their involvement in the Clone Wars, joins the Inquisitorius. Is killed during the Occupation of Mon Cala (*Jedi of the Republic: Mace Windu*, *Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith*).
- **Unidentified inquisitors** - Romantically involved and killed by Vader after the death of Eeth Koth (*Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith*).

This video by [Star Wars Explained](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIKlsX1qfGqKPt4KAW-JOZg) might be more informative than my list: [Every Imperial Inquisitor Revealed So Far (2019)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxcT60FUxBE).

Comment: *"[...] he falls to his death after attempting to fly away like an idiot"* :')

Comment: If we assume this a random selection of numbered Inquisitors, we can estimate there are ten or eleven total https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem I do not expect Star Wars to follow my analysis in future works